# Spring App cloudfoundry : connection refused

Tags: java, spring, cloud, cloud-foundry, connection-refused

I've a spring boot app running on cloudfoundry and I've to connect to an LDAP server to retrieve some user info, but when trying to connect to LDAP server it gives connection refused exception or for that matter for any external URL connection it gives that exception.
I read up on application security groups on cloudfoundry, but my org role is not allowing me to push the json config. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `cf space YOURSPACE --security-group-rules` to inspect the configured security groups applied to your space. Only admins can loosen them up.

Comment: Security groups would be the only thing inside of the CF platform that would restrict your outbound connection.  This doesn't mean security groups are the problem here.  It's entirely possible that your CF platform has been deployed onto a private network (i.e. there's no routable path to the Internet) and/or that your deployment is set up such that you need to route traffic through an HTTP Proxy to access the internet.  You really need to check with your platform administrator to see how they have configured the system.

Answer (score 0):

For updating security group, you can try with this command.

```
cf update-security-group SECURITY_GROUP PATH_TO_JSON_RULES_FILE
```